# Google Analytics Split Test -> Redirecting

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, http-status-code-301, ab-testing

I have a problem... I have set up a Google Analytics split test. If you go to [www.meebility.com](http://www.meebility.com) you will see that Google is adding some GET parameters. But that isn't the problem...

The problem is, if you klick on a link in the menu you get redirected to to homepage by Google Analytics... But I don't get why and how I can turn this off... Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

I have even googled but didn't found anybody with this problem...

Kind regards and Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Google Content Experiment then the experiment code goes only into the original page (it's the experiment code that does the redirection, and if it's on the variant page it might assign the user to the original variant and redirect them back there).

Since content experiments are deprecated in any case the best workaround would be to use Google Optimize, but simply removing the code from the variant page should help, too.

Comment: And should I add the code of Google Optimize to every page or also just to the original page?